# How to specify collection name while using spring data mongo repository?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am using spring data to fetch data for my application.

The repository class uses a mongo entity class which is being added as an upstream dependency to my project which means I don't have any control to change the source code of the class. As a result of this, I cannot use `@Document` annotation from `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping` to my mongo entity class.

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public interface DummyRepository extends MongoRepository<Dummy, String> {

    Page<Dummy> findAll(Pageable pageable);

}
```

Here, I don't have any control over source code of `Dummy` class so I can't add `@Document` to specify collection name for this class

How can I specify the *collection name* while using `DummyRepository` to query mongo collection?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use `@EnableMongoRepositories#repositoryFactoryBeanClass` with your own flavor of `MongoRepsoitoryFactoryBean` overriding `getEntityInformation(Class)`.
Unfortunately there's a bug ([DATAMONGO-2297](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2297)) in the code and for the time being you also need to customize `getTargetRepsoitory(RepositoryInformation)` as shown in the snippet below.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = CustomRepoFactory.class)
class config extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {
  // ...
}

class CustomRepoFactory extends MongoRepositoryFactoryBean {

  public CustomRepoFactory(Class repositoryInterface) {
    super(repositoryInterface);
  }

  @Override
  protected RepositoryFactorySupport getFactoryInstance(MongoOperations operations) {

    return new MongoRepositoryFactory(operations) {

      @Override
      public <T, ID> MongoEntityInformation<T, ID> getEntityInformation(Class<T> domainClass) {

       return new MappingMongoEntityInformation(
            operations.getConverter().getMappingContext().getPersistentEntity(domainClass)) {

          @Override
          public String getCollectionName() {
            return "customize-as-you-wish";
          }
        };
      }

      @Override // you should not need this when DATAMONGO-2297 is resolved
      protected Object getTargetRepository(RepositoryInformation information) {

        MongoEntityInformation<?, Serializable> entityInformation = getEntityInformation(information.getDomainType());
        return getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(information, entityInformation, operations);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried to attach this like `@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = CustomRepoFactory.class)` but get Spring Data Repository UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myRepositoryImpl'